# How does the MSMQ binding in WCF differ from WsHttp?

Tags: .net, wcf, msmq, wcf-binding

I'm trying to grok the MSMQ binding in WCF and wanted to know how it's different than the configuration for BasicHttp or WsHttp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest difference is that requests to the service have to be one-way (fire and forget) because there's no guarantee that they will be handled on the other end. Another obvious difference is that you need to ensure the queue(s) are configured before use.

Check out ['Queuing in WCF'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789048.aspx) on MSDN for more information.